# AJAX not sending data to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, send

In this script, data gets sent, but it does not send the updated value of the variable. Hard-coded data gets sent as expected. How can I solve this or go around it?

```
    username = '';  // supposedly these variables are global
    tree_name = ''; // I also tried plugging in- $('#username').data("username") -directly.. same results.

    $(function() {
        username = $('#username').data("username");    // updating value
        tree_name = $('#tree_name').data("tree_name"); // idem....
    });


    var options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/decision/p_tree2/",

        data: {
            username: username,     // this should send the data
            tree_name: tree_nam     // ...
        },

    success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);      
    }
};

$("form").ajaxForm(options);
```

PHP:

```
public function p_tree2 (){
    $data = Array();
    $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $data['tree_name'] = $_POST['tree_name'];

    echo print_r($data);    // result: both $data['username'] and $data['tree_name'] equal ""

}
```

Comment: It could be the positioning of the functions, one before the other could cause a problem. Such as the PHP function calling for the data from the other function before it is even created or vice versa

Comment: The place where you put those functions matters. In this case you're not putting the AJAX form code inside the jQuery `ready` code blocks. Try make their positions right first.

Comment: Which exactly is the jQuery "ready" code block?.. Thanks

Comment: Consider to provide html code block you are using in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Reformat your code like following. Also correct the typo you have in `tree_name` in data. You used `tree_nam`.

```
$(function() {
    var username, tree_name,options;

    username = $('#username').data("username");
    tree_name = $('#tree_name').data("tree_name");

    console.log(username); //make sure
    console.log(tree_name); // console outputs what you need to pass 

    options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/decision/p_tree2/",

        data: {
            username: username,     // this should send the data
            tree_name: tree_name     // ***correct this typo***
        },

        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    };

    $("form").ajaxForm(options);
});
```